# Is there a way to view only the instance methods of an object in Visual Studio's Intellisense?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

If I go to visual studio and type `MyEnumerable.`, I'll see a list of all the methods that can executed from that object.  This list shows extension methods as well, which is great, **but is there a way (a keboard shortcut?) to narrow this list down to not include extension methods?**

Comment: Native is the wrong term.  You mean instance methods.

Comment: @SLaks what about static methods? Do those only show up when an object is instantiated?

Comment: Unlike VB, you can't call static methods on an instance qualifier.  They will only show up if you write _YourType_ `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than removing `using System.Linq` from the top of the file, no.

However, you can look at the type in Object Browser, which will not show extension methods.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can but extension methods have a down arrow between the icon and the name, so you can at least tell them apart from the instance methods.